# LINQ to SQL Updating Problem

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I´m trying to update my Students table record using LINQ to SQL. The problem is when one of the Properties of the object changed and '**PropertyChanging**' Event is fired using '**SendPropertyChanging()**' method.

Please note:

1. student_id is a PK
2. data types are matched

Here is the full ArgumentException:

> GenericArguments[2], 'System.String', on
>   'System.Data.Linq.Mapping.PropertyAccessor+Accessor`3[T,V,V2]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'V2'.

Stack Strace

> at System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo
>   definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.PropertyAccessor.Create(Type objectType,
>   PropertyInfo pi, MetaAccessor storageAccessor)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaDataMember.MakeMemberAccessor(Type
>   accessorType, MemberInfo mi, MetaAccessor storage)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaDataMember.InitAccessors()
>   at
>   System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AttributedMetaDataMember.get_StorageAccessor()
>   at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.StandardTrackedObject.CreateDataCopy(Object
>   instance)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.OnPropertyChanging(Object
>   sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs args)    at
>   pro.Student.SendPropertyChanging() in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pro\Models\Student.vb:line 384    at
>   pro.Student.set_first_name(String value) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pro\Models\Student.vb:line 132    at
>   pro.WizardController.SetLanguageAndText(LanguageAndTextInfo ltInfo) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pro\Controllers\WizardController.vb:line 517    at
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)

Here is the Student.vb Class:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping
Imports System.ComponentModel

<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(name:="dbo.Students")> _
Public Class Student
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private Shared emptyChangingEventArgs As PropertyChangingEventArgs = New PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty)
    Private _student_id As System.Guid
    Private _first_name As String
    Private _last_name As String
    Private _email As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub


#Region "Properties"
    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(name:="student_id", Storage:="_student_id", DbType:="uniqueidentifier NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True, CanBeNull:=False)> _
    Public Property student_id() As System.Guid
        Get
            Return _student_id
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Guid)
            If ((_student_id = value) = False) Then
                SendPropertyChanging()
                _student_id = value
                SendPropertyChanged("student_id")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(name:="first_name", Storage:="_first_name", DbType:="nvarchar(250) NOT NULL", CanBeNull:=False)> _
    Public Property first_name() As String
        Get
            Return _first_name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If ((_first_name = value) = False) Then
                **SendPropertyChanging()**
                _first_name = value
                SendPropertyChanged("first_name")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(name:="last_name", Storage:="_last_name", DbType:="nvarchar(250) NOT NULL", CanBeNull:=False)> _
    Public Property language() As String
        Get
            Return _last_name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If ((_last_name = value) = False) Then
                **SendPropertyChanging()**
                _last_name = value
                SendPropertyChanged("last_name")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    <Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(name:="email", Storage:="_email", DbType:="nvarchar(250) NOT NULL", CanBeNull:=False)> _
    Public Property email() As String
        Get
            Return _email
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If ((_email = value) = False) Then
                **SendPropertyChanging()**
                _email = value
                SendPropertyChanged("email")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region

#Region "Linq Methods"
    Public Event PropertyChanging As PropertyChangingEventHandler Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Overridable Sub SendPropertyChanging()
        If ((Me.PropertyChangingEvent Is Nothing) = False) Then
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanging(Me, emptyChangingEventArgs)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub SendPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As [String])
        If ((Me.PropertyChangedEvent Is Nothing) = False) Then
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End If
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

This is how I'm trying to update a Student

```
Using context As New dbStudents(strConnString)

    Dim tmpStudent = (From p In context.Students
             Where p.student_id = CurStudent.student_id
             Select p).FirstOrDefault()

    tmpStudent.FirstName = CurStudent.FirstName
    tmpStudent.LastName = CurStudent.LastName
    tmpStudent.Email = CurStudent.Email

    context.SubmitChanges()

End Using
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the stack trace calling `SendPropertyChanging` causes `System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.OnPropertyChanging` to fire, which calls the `get` accessor of the same property in order to get data copy of the property before the change. However, you are using `String.Empty` as the property name, so my guess is that it cannot find the property by name.

Try changing the method SendPropertyChanging by adding property name, like you did with SendPropertyChanged.

Comment: No luck! Getting the same ArgumentException: {"GenericArguments[2], 'System.String', on 'System.Data.Linq.Mapping.PropertyAccessor+Accessor`3[T,V,V2]' violates the constraint of type 'V2'."}